# QTP Please guide me for beginner learning QTP [Quick Test Professional]

Tags: qtp

QTP Please guide me for beginning learning QTP [Quick Test Professional]

Comment: You can find number of text and video tutorials on internet.Also start practicing with the sample application that comes along with UFT.

Answer (score 0):

You have to qualify your question further. But for starters, you can download the trial version of QTP from HP and follow any one of the online/youtube tutorials for getting hands on.

Although I can't vouch for its quality, but [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=91XSG7qPp0o) could be a starting point.